# Why doesn't shift insert work in an xterm in Cygwin/X?

Tags: cygwin, copy-paste, xterm

shift insert works in mintty, but when I launch X with

/usr/bin/startxwin -- -xkblayout "us" -xkbmodel "pc105" -xkbvariant "altgr-weur" -xkboptions "altwin:meta-win,compose:rctrl,ctrl:nocaps" -listen tcp&

xterm only shows 2~ when pressing shift insert. How do I make this work correctly? Do I have to configure something special in .inputrc or .XResources to make this work? I never changed any of the cygwin defaults on this.

shift insert works as intended in emacs under X.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
xrdb -merge << EOF
XTerm*VT100.translations:       #override\n\
!Shift<Key>Insert : insert-selection(CLIPBOARD,PRIMARY)
EOF
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I still get 2~ after executing xrdb -merge.

Comment: When I start with your command `/usr/bin/startxwin ... &` and then run `xterm -display :0`, shift-insert works right away.

Comment: Thanks Philippe! I better reinstall, and if that doesn't work then it's time for a bug report.

Comment: It has to be with my physical keyboard. When I use the windows On-Screen Keyboard I am able to shift insert in an xterm.

Comment: Weird! I wouldn't think physical/On-Screen keyboards would make a difference.

Comment: I used xev to check the keycode. The windows On-Screen Keyboard returns 106 when I do a shift insert while the physical keyboard returns 90.

Comment: keycode value may not be that important, are they mapped to the same key ?

Comment: 106 = Insert while 90 = KP_Insert. I solved it. I only need a xmodmap -e 'keycode 90 = Insert" on my machine :)

Comment: Good catch ! :)

Comment: Check that the TERM variable is set correctly. Look to see if one of your startup scripts overrides the value provided by mintty or xterm with a hardcoded value. Then all your keys should be mapped correctly, instead of just the one you are changing here.

Answer (score 0):

I used xev to check the keycode.  The windows On-Screen Keyboard returns 106 when I do a shift insert while the physical keyboard returns 90.  Keycode 106 = Insert while keycode 90 = KP_Insert.

I only need a xmodmap -e 'keycode 90 = Insert" on my machine :)